# Can I include View in Model in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model, which Area is the Google map overlay(area) details and AreaData is the data used to render the area in the google map.

```
public class AreaDetailsViewModel
{
     public Area Area{get;set;}
     public AreaData Data{get;set;}
}
```

the problem now is i'm trying to use ajax call to retrieve view and data at the same time.

but if i return the whole data as json, i wont get view; if i return as html, i will include the areadata into html.

because i need to localize the view, i cannt just retrieve the data without the localized label info.

so can i include the view into model?

```
public class AreaDetailsViewModel
{
     public View AreaView{get;set;}
     public AreaData Data{get;set;}
}
```

but it seems weird, i really need your advice.

Comment: why you can't have a ajax call to retrieve the view (with data) ?

Comment: the AreaData can be polyline,rectangle,circle,polygon. to include it inside the html, is it too weird? i need to retrieve the data from html, and render it to the google map. it is just weird to me, it is make sense to handle it as json object.

Comment: @Jayantha forgot to tag you :)

Comment: What I feel is there is no different(of the outcome) between your approach and retrieving the view with an ajax call.

Comment: @Jayantha i think it is easlier to handle the json object than retrieve data from html.

Comment: Yes, but here you have a localized view. That will make client more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way MVC works is that you have a view (could be HTML, partial HTML, JSON, XML, ...) and a controller action which populates a model (all the data that the view needs in order to display) and passes this model to the view.

So in your example you could have a controller action which will be queried using an AJAX call and which passes the model to a partial view which will display this data in the desired format.

Comment: Yes,the problem is I want to combine partial HTML & JSON, I have to return a specified datatype, if i return partialview the google map overlay data also have to be stored inside the html; if return JSON(string), i have to get the view and put it into my model,like my 2nd example. am i miss something?

Comment: You should not return both HTML and JSON. If you return a partial view you have the model inside this partial, so you could update some hidden field or something which could be used to retrieve the required value in your AJAX success callback.

Comment: yes,but the extra data is used to render google map overlay.currently, i made 2 ajax call to the server, one is to retrieve html and the other is to retrieve the json data. it works, but just feel not a elegant way.

Comment: You could embed this extra data as a form of JSON inside the HTML using the `<script>` tag: `<script type="text/javascript">var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));</script>`. Now you could use the `model` variable inside your success callback. It will contain the entire model that was passed to this partial.

Comment: It works! i applied a hidden input inside the view and retrieve it after ajax call, convert json sring to object. thanks for your help!